# Put an link in d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Can we put a link of a json file for d3.json ?

My Link : 
[JSON File](http://blob:http://fiddle.jshell.net/9034e6cf-3067-4be7-bf47-0a42182d5841)

Example :

```
d3.json("blob:http://fiddle.jshell.net/9034e6cf-3067-4be7-bf47-0a42182d5841", function(error, json) {
            if (error) throw error;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. In d3 v3 / v4 you would do:

```js
d3.json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.log(error);
  console.log(json)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In d3 v5 you would do:

```js
d3.json("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3")
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the exemple, but try with my link too, it doesn't work .. :'( @ksav

Comment: Your link returns a 404

Comment: True, my bad. Thanks you again ;) @ksav